# LINQ to Entities query not projecting child collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What would cause this query. To start only projecting `c` without populating its child collection `ParcelValues`.

```
var result = (from c in _context.Parcels.Include("ParcelValues")
where c.STRAP == strap
select c);
```

I was running my app and the above would return a `result` object of type `IQueryable<Parcel>` with the property `Request.ParcelValues` populated with the correct records.  Now, for some reason, no matter how I try to use the include, only the Parcel fields are projected.

**GENERATED SQL**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[LAND_AREA] AS [LAND_AREA], 
[Project2].[STRAP] AS [STRAP], 
[Project2].[SITUS] AS [SITUS], 
[Project2].[ZIP_CODE] AS [ZIP_CODE], 
[Project2].[MAILING_ADDRESS] AS [MAILING_ADDRESS], 
[Project2].[PROPERTY_USE] AS [PROPERTY_USE], 
[Project2].[SUBDIVISION] AS [SUBDIVISION], 
[Project2].[DSCR] AS [DSCR], 
[Project2].[INCORPORATION] AS [INCORPORATION], 
[Project2].[SEC_TWP_RGE] AS [SEC_TWP_RGE], 
[Project2].[CENSUS] AS [CENSUS], 
[Project2].[WATERFRONT] AS [WATERFRONT], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project2].[STRAP1] AS [STRAP1], 
[Project2].[YEAR] AS [YEAR], 
[Project2].[LAND] AS [LAND], 
[Project2].[IMPROVEMENT] AS [IMPROVEMENT], 
[Project2].[JUST] AS [JUST], 
[Project2].[ASSESSED] AS [ASSESSED], 
[Project2].[TAXABLE] AS [TAXABLE]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[STRAP] AS [STRAP], 
    [Limit1].[SITUS] AS [SITUS], 
    [Limit1].[ZIP_CODE] AS [ZIP_CODE], 
    [Limit1].[MAILING_ADDRESS] AS [MAILING_ADDRESS], 
    [Limit1].[PROPERTY_USE] AS [PROPERTY_USE], 
    [Limit1].[SUBDIVISION] AS [SUBDIVISION], 
    [Limit1].[DSCR] AS [DSCR], 
    [Limit1].[LAND_AREA] AS [LAND_AREA], 
    [Limit1].[INCORPORATION] AS [INCORPORATION], 
    [Limit1].[SEC_TWP_RGE] AS [SEC_TWP_RGE], 
    [Limit1].[CENSUS] AS [CENSUS], 
    [Limit1].[WATERFRONT] AS [WATERFRONT], 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent2].[STRAP] AS [STRAP1], 
    [Extent2].[YEAR] AS [YEAR], 
    [Extent2].[LAND] AS [LAND], 
    [Extent2].[IMPROVEMENT] AS [IMPROVEMENT], 
    [Extent2].[JUST] AS [JUST], 
    [Extent2].[ASSESSED] AS [ASSESSED], 
    [Extent2].[TAXABLE] AS [TAXABLE], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[STRAP] AS [STRAP], 
        [Extent1].[SITUS] AS [SITUS], 
        [Extent1].[ZIP_CODE] AS [ZIP_CODE], 
        [Extent1].[MAILING_ADDRESS] AS [MAILING_ADDRESS], 
        [Extent1].[PROPERTY_USE] AS [PROPERTY_USE], 
        [Extent1].[SUBDIVISION] AS [SUBDIVISION], 
        [Extent1].[DSCR] AS [DSCR], 
        [Extent1].[LAND_AREA] AS [LAND_AREA], 
        [Extent1].[INCORPORATION] AS [INCORPORATION], 
        [Extent1].[SEC_TWP_RGE] AS [SEC_TWP_RGE], 
        [Extent1].[CENSUS] AS [CENSUS], 
        [Extent1].[WATERFRONT] AS [WATERFRONT]
        FROM [dbo].[PARCELS] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[STRAP] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PARCEL_VALUES] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[STRAP] = [Extent2].[STRAP]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[STRAP] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'0001020003'
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework, or are you using Linq-to-SQL? They're not the same thing! :)

Comment: Yeah sorry. I'm using Entity Framwork.

Comment: The query is clearly selecting the fields from the `PARCEL_VALUES` table. Are you absolutely sure there are related values in the table?

Comment: What do you mean by _only the Parcel fields are projected_? Technically, "projection" can loosely be defined as "what's in the SELECT clause". I sense that you might mean that only Parcel fields are _displayed_.

Comment: So, I may need to ask a different question. because, last night after fighting to get my app working. I discovered the child tables only load properly if my physical DB table Parcel_Values had it's primary keys removed, and I only assign the keys to the POCO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**KNOW THY DATA**

So, it ended up that my whole problem was being caused by a known design feature/bug of the Entity Framework (depending on how you look at it) and my data.  I was importing my keys from tables with nchar(25) into my tables with varchar(16) Most tables I was trimming the key before populating my targets.  I had forgotten to trim the key on the tables that would never seem to load, except when queried separately.  So, it turns out EF can't lazy load related tables with some having trailing whitespace in the keys (whitespace must match too).

Once I updated my script to load all my target sans whitespace.  Issue resolved.